# Training in Model target generator

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

While training a 3D model in model target generator after training the status of model is dataset outdated also the object is not being detected, how to solve this
[model target generator with status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j77E1.png)

I want the object to be detected ,also should the status be "Target generated"?

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that you've made a change to your project since the last time you generated the device database.

For example, the first time you set your guide views and then click “Generate Dataset”, the device database will be generated with those guide views. But, if you re-open the same project, modify a guide view and then go back to the home screen, it will say “dataset outdated” to indicate you've made changes.